# Preferred way of returning an immutable object

Tags: objective-c, types, immutability, mutable

If I have a method that looks something like this:

```
- (NSDictionary *)removeDataInDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {

    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];
    [mutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"key"];

    // Return option 1
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutableDictionary];

    // Return option 2
    return (NSDictionary *) mutableDictionary;
}
```

Is option 1 "better" codewise because it will really return a `NSDictionary` whilst option 2 will actually return a `NSMutableDictionary` disguised into a `NSDictionary` ?

Comment: It usually matters if you don't want the caller to modify a mutable object that is still going to be used somewhere else. In your example, it doesn't make a huge difference because `mutableDictionary`'s lifespan is limited to your method, but it's probably better in general to return an immutable copy. Also note that you can use `[mutableDictionary copy]` which is the same as option 1.

Comment: Aha, so `- copy` on a mutable object will return the immutable object type?

Comment: Yes, on Cocoa objects that exist in mutable/immutable type, `copy` always returns an immutable type, and `mutableCopy` returns a mutable type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return option 1 will create an immutable `NSDictionary` object, which is the way to go if you don't want it to be edited by any means.

The return option 2 will return an `NSMutableDictionary` anyways. Casting it to a `NSDictionary` will not make any difference

HOWEVER: When calling this method, you will see that it returns an `NSDictionary` and thus you will have to consider it as such outside, so unless you check the object class and then cast it to an NSMutableDictionary outside your method, it will look immutable outside.

Comment: The Apple discussion of [Object Mutability](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectMutability/ObjectMutability.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH5-SW1) is very thorough on this topic.  It's safest to make and return an immutable copy, but you don't have to.